# Wordpress - Uncode theme mobile items not showing

Tags: wordpress

I don't know what triggered this, but the navigation menu on the mobile version of my site no longer shows up when expanded. The hamburger menu opens just fine, but no items/pages are listed. The site in question is http://ataclaw.ca.

Comment: what browser are you using? clear browser cache. . I can see all items in your website from mobile view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use Walker nav menu once you are using bootstrap

https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

I had created an explanation here,

[Custom Nav in Wordpress not Loading Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945373/custom-nav-in-wordpress-not-loading-pages/49946363#49946363)